# why can't i fade in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, fade

How come the following code does not cause any fade effects?

```
var currentTicker =0;
function toggleTicker()
{
   var tickers = Ext.select('#toolbar .x-button').elements;

   if(tickers.length > 1)
   {
      Ext.Anim.run(tickers[currentTicker], 'fade', {out:true});
      currentTicker++;
      if(currentTicker == tickers.length)
              currentTicker = 0;

      Ext.Anim.run(tickers[currentTicker], 'fade', {out:false});
   }

}
```

I am trying to fade out the previous .x-button and fade in the next .x-button.  But none of the .x-buttons are fading in or out.  They are always visible.  I also don't have any javascript errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `autoClear` property to `false` otherwise the faded element reappears

Take a look at my answer to that post

[Working Example of Sencha Fade Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413842/working-example-of-sencha-fade-effect)

Here's the code that works...needs to use autoClear and Ext.get()

```
var currentTicker = 0;
function toggleTicker()
{
   var tickers = Ext.select('#toolbar .x-button').elements;

   if(tickers.length > 1)
   {
      Ext.Anim.run(Ext.get(tickers[currentTicker].id), 'fade', {out:true, duration:1000, autoClear:false});
      currentTicker++;
      if(currentTicker == tickers.length)
              currentTicker = 0;

      Ext.Anim.run(Ext.get(tickers[currentTicker].id), 'fade', {out:false, duration:1000, autoClear:false});
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

```
tickers.hide({type: 'fade', duration: 400})
```