# Working Example of Sencha Fade Effect

Tags: sencha-touch, fade

Can someone write me the full code to show me how I can fade in and fade out an html element with sencha touch 1?  Specifically, I need to know what is the necessary html, javascript and css files to include.

I've tried forever to get a simple fade effect to work on a div element, but no success.  Either I get method not found errors or nothing happens.  No one is answering my questions on the sencha forums.  I'm pretty sure i'm just missing something obvious.

**Additional Notes**

Here are things I tried and why they failed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nested List - Source Code Browser</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-touch.css" type="text/css" id="stylesheet_file" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sencha-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   Ext.setup({
      onReady: function() {

      //    Ext.get('mydiv').hide();
      //    Ext.get('mydiv').fadeOut(); // fadeOut() does not exist error
      //    Ext.Anim.run(Ext.get('mydiv'), 'fade', {out:true}); // does nothing
      //    Ext.Anim.run(Ext.getDom('mydiv'), 'fade', {out:true}); // does nothing
      }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body><div id="mydiv">hello world</div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
          Ext.setup({
                onReady: function() {

                    var bool = true;

                    var button1 = new Ext.Button({
                        text:'Fade',
                        id:'button1',
                        handler: function(){
                            Ext.Anim.run(button2, 'fade', {
                                out: bool,
                                autoClear:false
                            });
                            bool = !bool;
                            console.log("fade end");
                        }
                      });

                    var button2 = new Ext.Button({
                        text:'Fade'
                    });

                    var toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
                        dock:'top',
                        title:'Fade',
                        items:[button1,{xtype:'spacer'},button2]
                    });

                    new Ext.Panel({
                        fullscreen: true,
                        dockedItems: toolbar
                    });
                }
            });
```

**The auto clear attributes will keep the button hidden after fading**

Answer (score 2):

Here for prosperity is a fiddle of a concurrent fade in and fade out.

It uses a container with an absolute layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/R6cgc/13/

```
var into = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    width: 440,
    itemId: 'animTo',
    layout: {
        type: 'absolute'
    },
    style: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        padding: '20px'
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()           
});

var one = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    width: 360,
    height: 100,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    itemId: 'one',
    style: {
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }   
});

var two = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    width: 360,
    height: 500,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    itemId: 'two',
    style: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        opacity: 0
    }      
});


into.add(one);
into.add(two);
into.getEl().setHeight(two.getEl().getHeight() + 40);
two.hide();
var current = one;

Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'Fade',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            current.getEl().fadeOut({ duration: 2000});
            current = current == one ? two : one;
            current.getEl().fadeIn({ duration: 2000});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally figured it out.  As TDeBailleul explains, autoClear keeps elements hidden after fading.  Here's another example

**Example: Fade In**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nested List - Source Code Browser</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-touch.css" type="text/css" id="stylesheet_file" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sencha-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   Ext.setup({
      onReady: function() {
            Ext.Anim.run(Ext.get('mydiv'), 'fade', {out:false, duration:1000, autoClear:false});
      }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body><div id="mydiv" style="opacity:0;">hello world</div></body>
</html>
```

**Example: Fade Out**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Nested List - Source Code Browser</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-touch.css" type="text/css" id="stylesheet_file" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sencha-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   Ext.setup({
      onReady: function() {

         Ext.Anim.run(Ext.get('mydiv'), 'fade', {out:true, duration:1000, autoClear:false});

      }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body><div id="mydiv">hello world</div></body>
</html>
```